# Which PDO methods throw exceptions?

Tags: php, pdo

When establishing a new PDO db handler, I've got to wrap everything into a try-catch to prevent an error message that would print all db access data to the user.

But how about all the other methods like exec(), for example? Must I wrap all of these into a try-catch block? At which point is the PHP documentation telling that an method throws an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can set how errors are dealt with by PDO, using the [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) method, to set the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` *(error reporting)* option.

In particular, it is possible to configure PDO so it throws exceptions when there's an error, instead of reporting an "error" *-- that's what I generally do.*

Then, when a method can throw an exception, it should be indicated in it's documentation -- generaly, it's in the "Return value" section.

For instance, [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) can throw an exception -- depending on error reporting *(see what I wrote just before)* :

> If the database server cannot
>   successfully prepare the statement,
>   `PDO::prepare()` returns `FALSE` or
>   emits `PDOException` (depending on
>   error handling).

As a sidenote : if you find a function / method that throws an exception, and it's not indicated in its documentation, it might be a good idea to create a bug report (see http://bugs.php.net/ ), so that problem is corrected ;-)

*(Errors / mistakes / missing informations in the documentation are treated via the bug-tracker, like any other bug)*

Answer (score 2):

You can see if the method throws exceptions by looking at the manual.

If you look at the manual for [__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) you'll see at the bottom under Errors/Exceptions that it throws an exception.