# how to find record insert to mysql using commit()

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for this beginners question and i'm not a PHP developer, but now i'm trying to learn it.

i want to add record in MySQL data base and i'm using transactions lock.

my code is as below.

```
$SqlQuery="INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES('$PhotoID','$ProjectId','$Day','$barCode','$photoName','$PhotoXml')";

$waiting = true;
while($waiting) {
    try {
        // save border data
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SqlQuery);
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->execute();
        sleep(1);

        $x=$conn->commit();
        echo "x value-".$x;

        echo "Success";
        $waiting = false;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Failled :".$PhotoID."-".$PhotoID;
        if(stripos($e->getMessage(), 'DATABASE IS LOCKED') !== false) {
            // This should be specific to SQLite, sleep for 0.25 seconds
            // and try again.  We do have to commit the open transaction first though
            $conn->commit();
            usleep(250000);
        } else {
            $conn->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

in here as output it gives,

```
x value-1 Success
```

but actually this record doesn't add to the database.

**My Questions:**

1. Even the commit is successful(output 1) how does it not added to the database?
2. how can i check whether record is added to database? ( Is there any way to find it without write select statement?

Comment: i checked the database and its not added. my question is is there anyway to identify whether its added instead of writing select statement

Comment: Check what is returned by `$stmt->execute();` It should be 1. Also, please note that passing values like this: `$SqlQuery="INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES('$PhotoID','$ProjectId','$Day','$barCode','$photoName','$PhotoXml')";` opens your code for sql injections. Take a look at how to pass values with execute method

Comment: @FAngel it return empty value. what does that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you expect that PDOException will be thrown when statement is failed to execute. But as I can see, exception is not thrown by default in such cases. 
See how you can change that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967569/1558311)

Suppose in your case you should have a code like this:

```
$conn = new PDO($connection_string); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // this will force PDO to throw exception when SQL statement fails instead of simply setting an error.
```

Suppose this will work fine for you.

Please note that you should not use

```
$SqlQuery="INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES('$PhotoID','$ProjectId','$Day','$barCode','$photoName','$PhotoXml')";
```

Instead of that, you should use parameters binding:

```
$SqlQuery="INSERT INTO tab_photo VALUES(:PhotoID,:ProjectId,:Day,:barCode,:photoName,:PhotoXml)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($SqlQuery);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute(array(':PhotoID' => $PhotoID, ':ProjectId' => $ProjectId, ....));
sleep(1);
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for more details.

Comment: thanx a lot... this is what i looked for.... and also thanx for the additional information about coding errors..  :)